# Regex syntax in a C# application

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I am trying to figure out how to replace by a space all punctuation from a string but keeping one special character : '-'

For example, the sentence

> "hi! I'm an out-of-the-box person, did you know ?"

should be transformed into

> "hi  I m an out-of-the-box person  did you know  "

I know the solution will be a single line Regex expression, but I'm really not used to "think" in Regex, so what I have tried so far is replacing all '-' by '9', then replacing all punctuation by ' ', then re-replacing all '9' by '-'. It works, but this is awful (especially if the input contains some '9' characters) :

```
string s = @"Hello! Hi want to remove all punctuations but not ' - ' signs ... Please help ;)";
                s = s.Replace("-", "9");
                s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\W_]", " ");
                s = s.Replace("9", "-");
```

So, can someone help me writing a Regex that only catch punctuation different from '-' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing matches for the following regex with a space:

```
[^\w\s-]|_
```

This says, any character that is not a word character, digit, whitespace, or dash.

Comment: This would not replace underscores, which OP appears to want to replace. Also, the `\d` is superfluous as it is a subset of `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should help. Use [Character class subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) to remove some character from character classes.

```
var expected = Regex.Replace(subject, @"[_\W-[\-\s]]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `Linq`:

```
var chars = s.Select(c => char.IsPunctuation(c) && c != '-' ? ' ' : c);

var result = new string(chars.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I want a regex expression, I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: @Kabulan0lak This is a great solution, and much more easy to maintain that some regex solution that you didnt write yourself.

Comment: That was my first solution. But I really want to understand Regex expressions. I am reading some documentations and testing on a Regex generator but I have issues writing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Place everything you consider punctuation into a set `[` ... `]` and look for that as a *single* match character in a `(` ... `)` to be replaced. Here is an example where I seek to replace `!`, `.`, `,`,`'`, and `?`.

```
 string text = "hi! I'm an out-of-the-box person, did you know ?";

Console.WriteLine (

Regex.Replace(text, "([!.,'?])", " ")

);

// result:
// hi  I m an out-of-the-box person  did you know
```

**Update**

For the regex purist who doesn't want to specify a set one can use set subtraction. I still specify a set which searches for any non alphabetic character `\W` which will match all items including the `-`. But by using set subtraction `-[` ... `]` we can place the `-` to be excluded.

Here is that example

`Regex.Replace(text, @"([\W-[-]])", " ")`

```
// result:
// hi  I m an out-of-the-box person  did you know
```

Comment: Yep, I was reading "Character Class Subtraction"  like @SriramSakthivel suggested. It is what I need. Thanks again :)